# Is there an analytical solution to the inequality $\frac{1 + k({p}^{(k+1)/2)})}{p^k} < \frac{p}{p - 1}$ if one were to bound $k$ in terms of $p$?

Tags: inequality, numerical-methods, upper-lower-bounds, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions

My question is as is in the title:

> Is there an analytical solution to the inequality
> $$\frac{1 + k({p}^{(k+1)/2)})}{p^k} < \frac{p}{p - 1}$$ if one were to bound $k$ in terms of $p$?

Here, $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is a prime number and $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ is a positive integer.

**MOTIVATION**

This inquiry arises as an offshoot of [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618708).

In particular, by using the Arithmetic Mean-Geometric Mean Inequality, then we obtain
$$\sigma_1(p^k) \geq 1 + k (\sqrt{p})^{1+k} \tag{1}$$
so that
$$\frac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k} \geq \frac{1 + k (\sqrt{p})^{1+k}}{p^k} \tag{2},$$
where $\sigma_1(x)$ is the *classical sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.

But $\sigma_1(p^k)/{p^k}$ is equal to
$$\frac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k} = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p^k (p - 1)} \tag{3},$$
which is bounded from above by
$$\frac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k} = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p^k (p - 1)} < \frac{p^{k+1}}{p^k (p - 1)} = \frac{p}{p - 1} \tag{4}.$$

Using $(2)$ and $(4)$, we get
$$\frac{1 + k({p}^{(k+1)/2)})}{p^k} < \frac{p}{p - 1} \tag{5}.$$

**MY ATTEMPT**

I tried asking [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+%281+%2B+k%28%28p%29%5E%28%28k%2B1%29%2F2%29%29%29%2Fp%5Ek+%3C+p%2F%28p+-+1%29+for+k) for the solutions to Inequality $(5)$, it is giving me the following Inequality Plot:

[image: Inequality Plot]

I also noticed that Inequality $(5)$ is true *for all* $p$, when $k=1$.

Furthermore, I tried to rewrite Inequality $(5)$ as
$$k p^{(k+1)/2} (p - 1) < p^{k+1} - p + 1$$
$$k^2 p^{k+1} (p - 1)^2 < \left(p^{k+1} - p + 1\right)^2$$
but admittedly, I was not getting anywhere near to an analytical solution.

Basically, I would like to know whether a bound better than
$$k \geq \log_{5}\left(\frac{p}{p-4}\right) \tag{6}$$
could be obtained from assuming Inequality $(5)$, as detailed in this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4353765).  Hence, my question whether there was an analytical solution to Inequality $(5)$.

*Alas, this is where I get stuck!*

Comment: @mathlove:  Well, yes!  You can rewrite $\sigma_1(p^k)/p^k$ as
$$\frac{1 + k(\sqrt{p})^{1+k}}{p^k} \leq \frac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k} = \frac{p}{p - 1} - \frac{1}{p^k (p - 1)}$$
and see where that gets you.  =)

Comment: I deleted my comment to change a few words., but anyway, you got $(5)$ from $\dfrac{1 + k (\sqrt{p})^{1+k}}{p^k} \leqslant\dfrac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k}<\dfrac{p}{p - 1}$. This means that $(5)$ is weaker than $(4)$. So, I think that, from $(5)$, you cannot get a better result than $(4)$.

Comment: @mathlove: I asked W.A. to solve the simpler inequality
$$1 + k(\sqrt{p})^{1+k} \leq \sigma_1(p^k) = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p - 1},$$
and then from the resulting [Inequality Plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Solve+%281%2Bk%28sqrt%28p%29%29%5E%281%2Bk%29%29+%3C%3D+%28p%5E%28k%2B1%29+-+1%29%2F%28p+-+1%29+for+k), it seems that $k \geq 1$ is the solution.

Comment: It is obvious that $k\geqslant 1$ is the solution because you used AM-GM inequality to get $(1)$.

Comment: I apologize, @mathlove, but how is the fact that $k \geq 1$ is the solution obvious from using the AM-GM inequality to get $(1)$?

Comment: Note that the bound
$$k \geq \log_{5}\left(\frac{p}{p-4}\right)$$
does not result directly from considering $(3)$, but rather stems from the fact that
$$g(k,p) = \frac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k} + \frac{2p^k}{\sigma_1(p^k)}$$
is a *decreasing function* of $k$, and an *increasing function* of $p$, @mathlove.

Comment: The equality of $p+p^2+\cdots +p^k\geqslant kp^{(k+1)/2}$ is attained only when $p=p^2=\cdots=p^k$, i.e. $k=1$. If $k\gt 1$, then we have $p+p^2+\cdots +p^k\color{red}> kp^{(k+1)/2}$.

Comment: Yes, @mathlove.  Now, it is indeed obvious!  =)

Comment: I think that $(6)$ is weaker than an obvious inequality $k\geqslant 1$ since for $p\geqslant 5$, we have $k\geqslant 1\geqslant\log_{5}\left(\dfrac{p}{p-4}\right)$.

Comment: That is good to know, @mathlove!  If you could just consolidate your last few comments into an actual answer, I would be more than happy to upvote (and then accept) it!  =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You got $(5)$ from $\dfrac{1+kp^{(k+1)/2}}{p^k}\leqslant \dfrac{\sigma_1(p^k)}{p^k}<\dfrac{p}{p−1}$. This means that $(5)$ is weaker than $(4)$. (So, I think that, from $(5)$, you cannot get a better result than $(4)$.)

The inequality $(1)$ holds iff $k\geqslant 1$ since the equality of $p+p^2+\cdots +p^k\geqslant kp^{(k+1)/2}$ is attained only when $p=p^2=\cdots =p^k$, i.e. $k=1$, and if $k\gt 1$, then $p+p^2+\cdots +p^k\color{red}>kp^{(k+1)/2}$ holds.

I think that $(6)$ is weaker than an obvious inequality $k\geqslant 1$ since for $p\geqslant 5$, we have $k\geqslant 1\geqslant\log_{5}\left(\dfrac{p}{p-4}\right)$.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer.  (I merely wanted to collect some new thoughts that recently occurred to me, which are too long to be included in the *Comments* section.)

---

As in the original question, Inequality $(5)$
$$\frac{1 + k({p}^{(k+1)/2)})}{p^k} < \frac{p}{p - 1} \tag{5}$$
is equivalent to
$$k({p}^{(k+1)/2)}) (p - 1) < p^{k+1} - p + 1 \tag{7}$$
which is equivalent to
$$k({p}^{(k+1)/2)}) < p\cdot\left(\frac{p^k - 1}{p - 1}\right) + \frac{1}{p - 1} \tag{8}.$$

Rewriting $s(p^k) = (p^k - 1)/(p - 1)$ where $s(x)=\sigma(x)-x$ is the *aliquot sum* of $x$, then we have, from Inequality $(8)$:
$$k({p}^{(k+1)/2)}) < ps(p^k) + \frac{1}{p - 1} \tag{9}.$$

In other words, we have the lower bound
$$s(p^k) > \frac{1}{p}\cdot\left(k({p}^{(k+1)/2)}) - \frac{1}{p - 1}\right).$$

Define the two-variable function
$$f(k,p) = \frac{1}{p}\cdot\left(k({p}^{(k+1)/2)}) - \frac{1}{p - 1}\right).$$

It can be shown that
$$\frac{\partial f(k,p)}{\partial k} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot {p^{(k-1)/2}} \left(k \log p + 2\right).$$
Since $p$ is a prime number satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we know that $p \geq 5$.  In particular, this means that
$$\frac{\partial f(k,p)}{\partial k} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot {p^{(k-1)/2}} \left(k \log p + 2\right) > 0$$
so that $f(k,p)$ is an *increasing function* of $k$.  Since $k$ is a positive integer satisfying $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$, then we know that $k \geq 1$.  We infer that
$$f(k,p) \geq f(1,p) = 1 - \frac{1}{p(p-1)}$$
because $f(k,p)$ is an increasing function of $k$.

But we also know that
$$\frac{\partial f(1,p)}{\partial p} = \frac{2p - 1}{\left(p(p-1)\right)^2}$$
which is **positive** since $p \geq 5$.  This means that $f(1,p)$ is an *increasing function* of $p$, so that we obtain
$$f(1,p) = 1 - \frac{1}{p(p-1)} \geq f(1,5) = \frac{19}{20}.$$

> Thus, we conclude that
> $$s(p^k) > f(k,p) \geq f(1,p) \geq f(1,5) = \frac{19}{20} \tag{10}.$$

---

I now believe that Inequality $(10)$
$$\frac{p^k - 1}{p - 1} = s(p^k) > \frac{19}{20}$$
will result to a bound better than $(6)$
$$k \geq \log_{5}\left(\frac{p}{p-4}\right)$$
but I am not really 100% sure, as I have no proof.

Comment: $s(p^k) > \dfrac{19}{20}$ is equivalent to $k\gt \log_p\bigg(\dfrac{19p+1}{20}\bigg)$. This is better than $k \geqslant \log_{5}\left(\dfrac{p}{p-4}\right)$ iff $\log_p\bigg(\dfrac{19p+1}{20}\bigg)\geqslant \log_{5}\left(\dfrac{p}{p-4}\right)$ iff $p\geqslant 13$ according to W.A.

Comment: In fact, since $s(p^k)$ must be an **integer**, then $s(p^k) > 19/20$ **implies that** $s(p^k) \geq 1$.  This yields
$$\frac{p^k - 1}{p - 1} \geq 1 \iff p^k - 1 \geq p - 1 \iff p^k \geq p \iff k \geq 1,$$
which is better than
$$k \geq \log_5\left(\frac{p}{p-4}\right)$$
for $p > 5$.

Comment: Please write out your [last comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4639501/is-there-an-analytical-solution-to-the-inequality-frac1-kpk1-2#comment9791544_4639515) as an actual answer, so that I may be able to upvote it, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: Ah, I did not notice that. I think that my comment is not helpful, so I won't write it as an actual answer.

Comment: Agreed, @mathlove!  =)

Comment: @mathlove: Your earlier conclusion was better in perspective, which is why I invited you to write an actual answer about it.  Thank you for your time and attention!  =)